# XP Activation and Dual Booting

Tags: windows

I will need to keep an OEM version of XP on one machine to run a number of expensive older programs. I propose to leave that machine unconnected to the Internet so security support is not a problem. The question still remains though, if I need to do a clean re-install of that XP can I re-activate it after April 2014?

Also I need to build a new machine and dual boot another OEM copy of XP Professional (from a discarded machine) with Windows 8.1.

Does anyone see any problems in doing that?

Comment: A problem in what way?  You will be able to install Windows XP and activated until Microsoft says otherwise.

Comment: AFAIK MS doesn't really care about XP licenses and just activate any key that is valid, they don'T check anymore how often it was activated already as they did when XP was still new. So activating multiple copies shouldn't be any rpbolem - if it's legal to do so depends on the license you purchased.

Comment: "..and dual boot another OEM copy of XP Professional (from a discarded machine)" - Legally you can't do that. OEM OSs die with the system they were sold with.

Comment: Oh. yes. MIssed that "OEM". Well, my answer should still hold true - and I'm not going any further in this case, not supporting any fraud.

Answer (score 2):

Will I be able to activate a reinstall of XP after April, 2014?

> The end of Windows XP support *will not affect activation*, but rather
>   security updates and phone/online technical support.

> A spokesperson confirmed that activations will still be required for
>   retail installations of Windows XP post April 8. "Windows XP can still
>   be installed and activated after end of support on April 8," the
>   spokesperson noted.

> In a posting on PC World, Microsoft publicly responded to affirm that
>   Windows XP activation will be unaffected by the Windows XP support end
>   date.

[Source](http://www.zdnet.com/windows-xp-end-of-support-in-april-three-more-questions-answered-7000025151/), 
[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e689f11d-1bae-4b34-92af-33e87e11d45e/what-will-happen-to-windows-xp-activation-after-april-2014?forum=itproxpsp), 
[Source](http://www.technibble.com/windows-xp-support-ends-in-april-2014-what-technicians-need-to-know/), 
[Source](http://www.pcworld.com/article/250774/will_i_be_able_to_activate_xp_after_2014_.html)

As for:

> "..and dual boot another OEM copy of XP Professional (from a discarded
>   machine)"

Legally you can't do that. OEM OSs die with the system they were sold with.

Comment: `"OEM OSs die with the system they were sold with."` Interesting. But what defines "the system"? The case? CPU? Motherboard? Primary hard disk? Any two of the three?

Comment: That's always been up in the air, but primarily it's the motherboard.

Comment: So I can't replace the motherboard in an off-the-shelf system without buying a new copy of Windows?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You can replace the MB if it's being replaced due to the existing one failing.  Otherwise, changing the MB is a "new" system and requires a new OEM license.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart See the MS [Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en-gb/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx#fbid=qEgAyLKmGzk): "Generally, an end user can upgrade or replace all of the hardware components on a computer—except the motherboard—and still retain the licence for the original Microsoft OEM operating system software. If the motherboard is upgraded or replaced for reasons other than a defect, then a new computer has been created."

Answer (score 0):

Although MS's official statement is that users should be able to activated WinXP more or less indefinitely, for a lot users internet activation does not work and the phone numbers provided in the activation dialogue have changed.

Therefore I want to link here to (my) follow-up question on how to activate WinXP nowadays (with a focus on non-online activation methods): [How do I activate Windows XP nowadays (in 2019)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1502796/how-do-i-activate-windows-xp-nowadays-in-2019)